# After-script for skipped gitlab pipeline job

Tags: gitlab-ci

My question is same as title.

Is after_script execute even if gitlab pipeline job is skipped ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No. The `after_script:` is part of the job. If the job does not start, the `after_script:` section will not be run.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What if I add after_script not to the job level , but at the global level ? Asking this because if I skipped the pipeline, the pipeline is created but later skipped. I can see any entry for pipeline marked as skipped.

Comment: My use case is basically creating a custom badge using anybadge. The default pipeline status badge shows all states - skipped, unknown, passed, failed. I want a badge for pipeline timestamp irrespective of state. That is, even if pipeline skipped, along with default gitlab pipeline status badge , I want to show my timestamp badge. So I want to run this anybadge code somewhere. after_script was one option if it ran irrespective if pipeline is skipped.